# Spring Security Not Setting JSESSIONID Cookie

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When a user is registering, I am trying to also authenticate them in the same step.  I've looked around online, and this seems to be the way to do so:

```
UserDetails userDetails userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
// Set authenticated
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
if (auth.isAuthenticated()){
    // This is hit every time, seemingly signaling 
    // that authentication is happening
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
}
```

However, this is not setting the JSESSIONID cookie, and therefore the first time the user tries to access a protected resource, they must login again.  Any thoughts on how to fix this? I am using the 4.0.1.RELEASE version of Spring Security.

I am also setting the following in my config, but I am not sure if it might be related:

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);
http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my server had become corrupt somehow.  It was also rejecting api calls randomly, so I did a fresh install of the server and now it all works.